# django is_valid returns false for model form even though all fields have a value

Tags: python, django

Why does this returns an invalid form? I click browse, select a csv file, select a user, check the boolean box, and submit.

upload.html

```
<form action = "" method = "POST" class = "mtop-25">
 {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type = "submit" >Upload File</button>
</form>
```

models.py

```
class Csv(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='csvs', max_length = 100)
    public = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "File id: {}".format(self.id)
```

forms.py

```
class CsvForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Csv
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {'file_name' : 'Browse'}
```

views.py

```
def upload(request):
form = CsvForm
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CsvForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    return HttpResponse(form.is_valid())
else:
    return render(request, 'upload/upload.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: are you sure your request contains the user / user id in POST?

Comment: `defines the enctype as "multipart/form-data"` in your **upload.html** file form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define `enctype` attribute in the form `tag` while dealing with files.

```
<form action = "" method = "POST" class = "mtop-25" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```